# How to make HTTP requests using Plink

Tags: putty, http, plink

On Windows I want to make simple HTTP requests to find bugs in my scripts. Of course I usually use more convenient tools (like the "REST client"-plugin in Firefox) but now I want to go one level deeper.

**How can I make HTTP requests in Windows from command line?**

I tried to use Plink (from PuTTY):

```
plink -telnet -P 80 servername GET /index.php
```

But the server keeps telling me, that

> The request verb is invalid.

Probably it ignores the `GET /index.php` part.

- I don't have `telnet` (I'm using my company's PC and I can't install that Windows feature here)
- I want to keep it low-level (not following any redirects, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use the Telnet protocol to implement the HTTP. PuTTY will send some Telnet control sequences that break the HTTP protocol. You need to use a "raw" connection using the `-raw` switch (instead of the `-telnet`).
2. You can specify the command on Plink command-line with the SSH protocol only. It does not work with the raw connection or the Telnet. But you can use an input redirection.

This should work:

```
echo GET /index.php | plink.exe -raw -P 80 servername
```

---

Though you better use some more powerful tool. Examples:

- [Wget for Windows](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)
- PHP: Just download a [ZIP archive with Windows build of PHP](https://windows.php.net/download), extract `php.exe` and `php5ts.dll` and you have a full implementation of HTTP with a full featured scripting language. No installation needed.